# Round while groupping by in pandas with agg function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there any posibilities to round the mean of C in this group by?

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'sum', 'C':'mean'})
```

Comment: `df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'sum', 'C':lambda x: np.round(np.mean(x))})`

Comment: Why not round the results in a separate line? That would be more readable instead of piling up too many things in one line.

Answer (score 10):

You can **place round after the aggregation** as shown below:

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B':'sum', 'C':'mean'}).round(2)
```

In an aggregation it is not possible to include round inside. Hence you can place round after the aggregation. It is a simple and effective way.

Round(2) will round it off to two decimal places. You can change 2 to include whatever number of decimal places you want to round off the numbers to. For eg to round off to 3 decimal places you can use .round(3) and so on.